# why is BlobProvider generating URL only the first time the application runs?

Tags: reactjs, blob, react-pdf

I am using react-pdf/renderer ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-pdf/renderer)  to generate a PDF file in my react-application. The code is as below:

```
           <BlobProvider document={<Document />}>
              {({ url, blob }) => {
                return (
                  <a href={url} target="_blank">
                    View as PDF
                  </a>
                );
              }}
            </BlobProvider>;
```

The issue is that for the first time when the application runs, the URL is generated and the PDF gets opened on another tab. However if I navigate to another tab then come back to this component and try to generate pdf the url is returned as null in the href instead of the document URL. What is it that I am missing? TIA

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the react-pdf version you are using on this scenario ?